# change Date Format C#

Tags: c#, date

I am creating a web app in which if a user wants to show the data between the particular date he enter the date in the textbox with the help of ajax calender extender,
There are two textboxes 
1 From date
2 To date

```
9/1/2016

9/16/2016
```

And this is how the date is coming but i want to convert the date before validating the dates from the database,

And I want the date format to be like the following

```
2015-10-26

2016-09-28
```

Comment: Read date as `DateTime` object, not as a string. Format date only for displaying it in UI.

Comment: Dates have no format, It is  how you show them that requires a 'format'. This is done applying to Dates a conversion to a string. It is not clear the precise context. If you use a TextBox to input dates then you have no control on how your user types these dates. Use a DateTimePicker instead that allows you some control on the display of your date value

Comment: @Steve the date is coming from calender extender and the format remainse same

Comment: you wants to convert at database side OR C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let assume you have two string

```
string date="10-10-2016"; 
string datecon="";


datecon=DateTime.ParseExact(datefrm, "dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
//26-10-2015
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),110)
//2015-10-26
 CONVERT(char(10), GetDate(),126)
```

You can convert your date time like this

Answer (score 0):

Format will be the better option instead of converting into varchar and display it. But you can use Format if you are using SQL Server 2012 or above

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';  

SELECT FORMAT(@d,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),120)
```

and output is **2016-09-17**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below piece of code:

```
DECLARE @INPUT_DATE_1 DATETIME = '9/1/2016'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @INPUT_DATE_1, 126) as FORMATTED_DATE_1


DECLARE @INPUT_DATE_2 DATETIME = '9/16/2016'

SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @INPUT_DATE_2, 126) as FORMATTED_DATE_2
```